# 2011 27'' iMac kernel panic

Tags: macos, imac, memory, kernel-panic

My iMac has been giving Kernel Panic recently.
its 2011 27in iMAC, and i added 8G RAM about one and half month ago. Around 2 weeks later, the error started and i upgraded the firmware. now im upgrading the OS X to Mavericks, but i dont think that will help.
Any solution? here is the report

```
    Interval Since Last Panic Report:  57898 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          4
Anonymous UUID:                    681A3C63-2108-445E-BF94-C699A7C61BB4

Fri Mar 21 10:51:25 2014
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80002c4794): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80002ab8ae, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000000011bb26aec, CR3: 0x0000000086ef000d, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x934c0395a0fac321, RBX: 0xfffffe801887ce60, RCX: 0x5557eebe77df5d36, RDX: 0xffffff801d7efd90
RSP: 0xffffff81605d3c20, RBP: 0xffffff81605d3cb0, RSI: 0x0000000100c28000, RDI: 0xffffff801d7efd90
R8:  0xffffff80008bee08, R9:  0xffffff80008bee10, R10: 0xfffffe80543f2800, R11: 0x00080000002ca7f1
R12: 0xfffffe8000000000, R13: 0x0000000100d00000, R14: 0x00000000002f1473, R15: 0x000000000000040a
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff80002ab8ae, CS: 0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
CR2: 0x000000011bb26aec, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Faulting CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81605d38d0 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff81605d3950 : 0xffffff80002c4794 
0xffffff81605d3b00 : 0xffffff80002da55d 
0xffffff81605d3b20 : 0xffffff80002ab8ae 
0xffffff81605d3cb0 : 0xffffff80002abeca 
0xffffff81605d3cf0 : 0xffffff8000273c46 
0xffffff81605d3de0 : 0xffffff8000274a3a 
0xffffff81605d3e10 : 0xffffff8000237919 
0xffffff81605d3e50 : 0xffffff8000544d49 
0xffffff81605d3ea0 : 0xffffff8000551d18 
0xffffff81605d3f10 : 0xffffff8000553755 
0xffffff81605d3f50 : 0xffffff800021e143 
0xffffff81605d3f90 : 0xffffff80002c3d3a 
0xffffff81605d3fb0 : 0xffffff80002da52c 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: ReportCrash

Mac OS version:
11G63b

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5
System model name: iMac12,2 (Mac-942B59F58194171B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11113416075054
last loaded kext at 3643266274545: com.apple.filesystems.afpfs    9.8.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8104f000, size 356352)
last unloaded kext at 238066755629: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI         5.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f80aab000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs     9.8.1
com.apple.nke.asp_tcp     6.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs    1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor    1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs   3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver  122
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient      3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA     2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.75
com.apple.kext.ATIFramebuffer      7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet        1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager      4.0.8f17
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin  5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver     1.2.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl        3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC      1.6.0
com.apple.ATIRadeonX3000  7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight      170.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl       1.0.33
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics  7.3.2
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController         4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient         3.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader  3.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI       2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController 312
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter      404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage      2.1.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless       1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib      1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache      33
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub       5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI      4.9.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40  505.67.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet          3.2.4b8
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort     2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI    5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons        1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC     1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET   1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS       1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC        1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient       195.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall    3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine 1.4
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet     8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement         195.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword      1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers     1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib   2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP   2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface        80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily         10.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC     3.1.3d10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy        5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily        1.8.6fc18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib      1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController     2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily          2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily        5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI   1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink  1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSource       1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.10d0
com.apple.kext.ATI6000Controller  7.3.2
com.apple.kext.ATISupport     7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport     2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily   2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard        160.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard       160.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController        4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter  1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter     1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily      1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter      1.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice     3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily         1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily      1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily         1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice      3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass         3.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily    3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub     5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite     5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI  1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily      2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient     5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family       420.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController        1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily        2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily        2.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily      1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox     177.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages   331.7
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily     1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore       28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform       1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily   2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily         1.4
Model: iMac12,2, BootROM IM121.0047.B1F, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 12 GB, SMC 1.72f2
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424353302D444A2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424353302D444A2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3130322E413030472020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344743363442384847304E532D444920
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x9A), Atheros 9380: 4.0.67.5-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: FireWire, FireWire, fw0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST31000528AS, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5690H
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 3
USB Device: Officejet 6200 series, 0x03f0  (Hewlett Packard), 0x4b11, 0xfa130000 / 6
USB Device: USB Receiver, 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.), 0xc52b, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8215, 0xfa111000 / 7
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x850b, 0xfa200000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0xfd130000 / 5
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x024f, 0xfd132000 / 6
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 4
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfd110000 / 3
iMac, OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.5)
```

Comment: Is there any pattern? For example, does it happen when in a certain app, or a device is plugged in?

Comment: i dont think so. it also shuts off when i just leave it on.

Comment: "i added 8G RAM about one and half month ago." This is almost certainly your issue. Who was the vendor? Take one stick out and test. Take the other stick out and test. Additionally, you can run [Rember](http://www.kelleycomputing.net/rember/) on the modules. I advise skipping all this though, returning them and receiving a new pair --> all signs point to a faulty stick.

Answer (score 1):

Something I learned at Apple support in Austin many years ago: The first rule of troubleshooting is "Isolate And Identify." Pound that into your brain.

In other words, strip the system down to the minimum, unplug EVERYTHING that is not needed to boot the computer, undo any changes (especially hardware) that were made to the computer, no matter how long ago they were done. Uninstall any software you recently installed, undo any changes you recently made. Create a new (admin) user and see if it repeats in that login.

THEN if you can get it to stop crashing or acting wrong start re-doing the changes ONE AT A TIME till they start to recur. Sometimes the strings and smallest change can cause problems. Even if it doesn't seem reasonable to you, it could be the problem.

Upgrading to Mavericks MIGHT fix the problem. Removing the new(isn) RAM might also fix the problem. Failing those things start unplugging and uninstalling...

Answer (score 1):

That looks (the report) very similar to a problem I've got.  It started with frozen screens & Kernel Panics, every now and again, slowly its got worse, so I decided to investigate.  After doing several things, I decided to do an AHT test (hardware test = pressing "D" on start up), after doing an "Extended Test" the result was 4/MEM/9/40000000: 0xb73ce318 which I'm pretty certain means a bad RAM chip?  Which means finding the bad RAM chip & "retiring it" (taking all but one out & testing them one at a time, until you find the culprit)?
I have a late 2010 27" iMac & Mavericks 10.9.4